# Как в тексте получить текст между тегами. Через функцию, а не работу с DOM API

Tags: javascript, строки, задание-на-собеседовании

Дана задача.

Есть текст, в котором присутствуют теги, в данном случае тег `<span>`. Нужно перебрать строку, и на выходе получить строку, которая через запятую перечисляет содержимое тегов `<span>` из начального текста.

Усложнённая задача.

Функция принимает второй параметр, а именно сам тег. И в тексте выбирает содержимое только того тега, который указан, даже если присутствуют другие теги.

PS: регулярные выражения использовать нельзя.

Так же входная строка всегда валидна, и не содержит символов  '<' и '>', кроме как открытие/закрытие тега.

```
const input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit</span> amet, qui in ea  velit esse,<span>voluptate</span> quam nihil molestiae <span>consequatur</span>'
const getText = (input: string) => {
...
}

или

const getTagValue = (input: string, tag: string) => {
...
}

const output = 'sit, voluptate, consequatur'
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134321/discussion-on-question-by-bob---------).

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите за старт такой пример

```
const input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit</span> amet, qui in ea  velit esse,<span>voluptate</span> quam nihil molestiae <span>consequatur</span>'
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
var elems = doc.querySelectorAll("span");
var arr =[];
var len = elems.length;
for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        arr.push(elems[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
var result = arr.join(", ");
console.log(result);
```

либо такой вариант

```
const input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit</span> amet, qui in ea  velit esse,<span>voluptate</span> quam nihil molestiae <span>consequatur</span>'
var arr = input.match(/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/g).map(function(val){
   return val.replace(/<\/?span>/g,'');
});
var result = arr.join(", ");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: А `querySelectorAll` и `childNodes` это случаем не работа с DOM ?

Comment: @UModeL точно, а во втором варианте регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 1):

Для достаточно строгих ограничений указанных в вопросе достаточно использования метода [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

1. Ищется открывающий тег
2. Ищется закрывающий тег
3. получается текст между найденными тегами.
4. Повторять, пока в остатке строки присутствует открывающий тег.

Вторым параметром `.indexOf` принимает индекс с которого надо начинать поиск.
Для получения подстроки можно воспользоваться методом [`.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Таким образом, для случая отсутствия вложенных тегов, функция может выглядеть так:

```
const getText = (input) => {
  var openTag = `<span>`; // определяем открывающий тег
  var closeTag = `</span>`; // определяем закрывающий тег

  var result = [];

  for (var i = input.indexOf(openTag); i > -1; i = input.indexOf(openTag, i)) { // крутимся в цикле, пока есть открывающий тег
    var textIndex = i + openTag.length; // получаем индекс начала текста между тегами
    var closeIndex = input.indexOf(closeTag, textIndex); // индекс начала закрывающего тега
    result.push(input.substring(textIndex, closeIndex)); // берем подстроку между тегами
    i = closeIndex + closeTag.length; // сдвигаем индекс, откуда надо начинать искать новый открывающий тег
  }
  return result;
}
```

Для второй функции изменения тривиальные. Достаточно собирать `openTag`, `closeTag` с помощью переданного параметра:

```
var openTag = `<${tag}>`;
var closeTag = `</${tag}>`;
```

Остальной код общий.

```js
const input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit</span><span></span> amet, qui in ea  velit esse,<span>voluptate</span> <div>quam</div>  nihil<div></div> molestiae <span>consequatur</span>';
const getText = (input) => {
  var openTag = `<span>`;
  var closeTag = `</span>`;

  var result = [];
  for (var i = input.indexOf(openTag); i > -1; i = input.indexOf(openTag, i)) {
    var textIndex = i + openTag.length;
    var closeIndex = input.indexOf(closeTag, textIndex);
    result.push(input.substring(textIndex, closeIndex));
    i = closeIndex + closeTag.length;
  }
  return result;
}


const getTagValue = (input, tag) => {
  var openTag = `<${tag}>`;
  var closeTag = `</${tag}>`;

  var result = [];

  for (var i = input.indexOf(openTag); i > -1; i = input.indexOf(openTag, i)) {
    var textIndex = i + openTag.length;
    var closeIndex = input.indexOf(closeTag, textIndex);
    result.push(input.substring(textIndex, closeIndex));
    i = closeIndex + closeTag.length;
  }
  return result;
}

const getText2 = input => getTagValue(input, 'span');

const output = 'sit, voluptate, consequatur'

console.log(getText(input));
console.log(getText2(input));
console.log(getTagValue(input, 'span'));
console.log(getTagValue(input, 'div'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативное решение - использование метода [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

1. Разбиваем строку по открывающему тегу
2. Пропускаем первый элемент, всем часть, которая стоит перед первым открывающим тегом - она не нужна
3. разбиваем каждую получившуюся часть по закрывающему тегу с лимитом 1

Например:

```
input.split(openTag) // Разбиваем строку по открывающему тегу 
     .slice(1) // Пропускаем первый элемент
     .flatMap(textWithClose => textWithClose.split(closeTag, 1)); // разбиваем каждую получившуюся часть по закрывающему тегу с лимитом 1
```

```js
const input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit</span><span></span> amet, qui in ea  velit esse,<span>voluptate</span> <div>quam</div>  nihil<div></div> molestiae <span>consequatur</span>';
const getText = (input) => {
  var openTag = `<span>`;
  var closeTag = `</span>`;

  return input.split(openTag)
    .slice(1)
    .flatMap(textWithClose => textWithClose.split(closeTag, 1));
}


const getTagValue = (input, tag) => {
  var openTag = `<${tag}>`;
  var closeTag = `</${tag}>`;

  return input.split(openTag)
    .slice(1)
    .flatMap(textWithClose => textWithClose.split(closeTag, 1));
}

const getText2 = input => getTagValue(input, 'span');

const output = 'sit, voluptate, consequatur'

console.log(getText(input));
console.log(getText2(input));
console.log(getTagValue(input, 'span'));
console.log(getTagValue(input, 'div'));
```